# solsplace calendar gives error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Pagination_object::get_template()"

Tags: error, solspace-calendar

I'm using solspace calendar, but its gives Fatal Error "Call to undefined method Pagination_object::get_template() in /content/system/expressionengine/third_party/calendar/mod.calendar.php on line 5363"

line number 5363 script given below

```
if ($this->ee_version >= '2.4.0')
{
    $channel->pagination->get_template();
}
else
{
    $channel->fetch_pagination_data();
}
```

FYI:
EE: 2.8.1

Calendar: 1.8.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to Calendar 1.8.6. It's the recently released version that is compatible with EE 2.8.x.

- **Changelog**: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/change_log/#v1.8.6
- **Software Compatibility Table**: http://www.solspace.com/software/compatibility